# read a binary file opened by fopen("ab") (add,binary)

Tags: c++, c, file, binary

I am just learning to work with `FILE`s. My problem is this:
when I want to read a binary file that was opened by `fopen("example.dat", "ab")`, it shows something like:

[this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MEpg.jpg)

But when I open file by `fopen("example.dat", "wb")`, it works!

Here are my test programs:

to write on file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *save = fopen("save.dat", "wb");
    char str[5][40];
    while (i < 5) {
        gets(str[i]);
        fwrite(str[i], sizeof(char), 40, save);     
        i++;
    }
}
```

to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char str2[100][400];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *load = fopen("save.dat", "rb");
    if (!load) {
        printf("cant open file!");
        return;
    }
    fread(str2[i], sizeof(char), 40, load);
    while (!feof(load)) {
        puts(str2[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        fread(str2[i], sizeof(char), 40, load);
    }
}
```

I need `"ab"` because it is about saving info of a game and it shouldn't delete after closing program or run it again .

Comment: Use an editor that can display the binary contents.

Comment: @user3121023  i tried it delete last saved data on file

Comment: heeyyyy whyy nagative votes!!! i am just a poor Engineer student

Comment: If I change the first program to use `"ab"` instead of `"wb"`, the second program will still read it properly.  What exactly is the problem?  You should post the code that is problematic, not the working code.

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work - it's not the best design, but it should at least work.

Comment: You could also open it as `"rb+"` which is read, binary, append.  You can then `fseek` and write into the file.

Comment: no, when you change it to "ab" you see some unwanted signs like picture before each string this the problem @dbush

Comment: You should learn why [`while(!feof)` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Not when I tested it.  You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're having.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer i see .but when you exit program and run it again "w" delete all the things that you saved on file instantly after open it so i should use "a" because i need last data

Comment: Or check if it exists and if it does, rb+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is opening the file with `"ab"` does not truncate it, therefore you are appending to the same file and keep reading whatever incorrect output was written there first.

In addition, your code has several problems:

- Never use `gets()`.  It was removed from the C Standard because it cannot be told how large the buffer is a therefore cannot be used safely.
- Your test for end of file is incorrect: never use `feof()`, because it does not do what you think it does.  It can only tell you if the end of file has been encountered by a stream function that actually tried to read past it. You can simply test the return value from `fread`.
- The prototype for `main` is either `int main(void)` of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
- You should check for correct boundaries to prevent reading past the end of the `str2` array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str2[100][400];
    FILE *load = fopen("save.dat", "rb");
    if (!load) {
        printf("cant open file!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && fread(str2[i], sizeof(char), 40, load) == 40; i++) {
        puts(str2[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(load);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx for your correction and help it was so helpful, i tried your new code but it didn't worked correct again same problem @chqrlie

Comment: @AliZeynali: did you first remove the `save.dat` file?

Comment: I didn't remove but delete all data chqrlie

Comment: @AliZeynali: what do you mean by *delete all data*? did you delete the file with `del save.dat` or `rm save.dat` or `unlink("dave.dat");` or did you do something else?

Comment: I just opened file and delete every thing in file and save i didn't delete the file

Comment: Okay, if you do that, try running `hexdump save.dat` on the command line (assuming you're using a linux-style system).  I reckon that the file won't actually be empty.  You've somehow left some extra characters in there.  Another way would be to look at the exact file size in bytes (it should be zero).  Better to actually delete it before running your test.  It may have got this way because you originally wrote data to it from an uninitialised array.  Whatever editor you used to "delete" the contents might have left some unprintable characters in there.

Comment: THANKS CHQRLIE AND PADDY IT WORKED WHEN I DELETED WHOLE FILE(in last times i opened file and delete it's content but now i deleted file it self and let "ab"  make its file and it worked :DDD i'm not on earth now:DDDDD